# Prereq sciences for Neuroscience

Tags: neuroscience

I've been a professional software developer for 7 years and have gotten into EdTech over the last 4 years. I'm building my own EdTech apps for students, and in doing so I decided to enroll in a Master's in Cognitive Science in Education program to develop a better understanding of how students think and learn.

In my program, I'd like to build this understanding from a high (cognitive) and low (neuroscience) perspective to understand the underlying mechanics in cognitive processes.

My program has several Neuroscience foundations courses I can take, but I haven't taken sciences since college a decade ago. I'm taking these Neuroscience foundations courses this fall, but I'd like to be fully prepared beforehand.

I'm wondering which courses I definitely need to have a strong foundation in (Biology 101? Chem 101?, or do I not need any prior training beforehand?) prior to beginning in the fall. And if you'd recommend good courses, or Moocs, with textbooks, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: I just went to my university library and read a pile of books when I did my paper, so I found some of the types of books that existed. The ones closer to biology was easier to understand, and let me know about different cell types and how the brain worked and how the neural pathways went in the body etc, a bit closer to psychology. The ones about firing neurons and modeling the brain as a bunch of them seemed to have a lot of applied statistics that probably went over my head. Some of them had a connection to physics and electromagnetism, they were slightly easier to understand.

Comment: I think the ones that I had most problem with had tons of like correlation graphs and some kind of chaos theory, but it felt like I was missing some kind of measurement, experimentation and modeling foundation to get them. Especially since they never wrote what was on the axes... that was expected to be understood...